# How to limit field choices related to another table in database?

Tags: django

I'm working on simple expenses manager. Every user is able to add/remove/edit an Operation, which represents expense or earning. However I have noticed a bug - while adding new Operation it is possible to choose other users Accounts and Categories.

Here is my Operation model:

```
class Operation(models.Model):

    def get_category_color(self):
        return Category.objects.get(name=self.category).color

    types_tuples = ((-1, 'expense'), (1, 'earning'))

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=types_tuples)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    color = property(get_category_color)
```

OperationCreate view:

```
class OperationCreate(CreateView, OperationMixIn):

    model = Operation
    form_class = OperationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_operations')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        operation = form.save(commit=False)
        operation.currency = Account.objects.get(pk=form.instance.account_id).currency
        self.update_account_balance(form)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(OperationCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

and OperationForm:

```
class OperationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Operation
        fields = ['account', 'type', 'category', 'date', 'amount']
```

The question is how can I limit choices for Account and Category that are available during posting new Operation? I would like user to see only those which are related to his/her account.

I tried `limit_choices_to` as a parameter for `models.ForeignKey(Account)` and `models.ForeignKey(Category)` in Operation model but couldn't make it work that way.

I assume I need to use a query which will return only Accounts and Categories related to the current user. However I have no clue how and where should I apply it.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

OperationForm edited due to @efkin suggestion:

```
class OperationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Operation
        fields = ['account', 'type', 'category', 'date', 'amount']

    def __ini__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OperationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
        self.fields['account'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Account.objects.filter(user=user))
        self.fields['category'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(user=user))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple Form with [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) fields for foreign keys.

Comment: Hey, thanks for an answer. I looked it up and I have related question.

I assume that I could modify my Operation form in the following way I showed in the edit I made to my original post. I'm not sure though how can I pass `request.user` from the views.

Comment: Okay, I found the way to pass this `request.user` parameter. See the solution below :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I did some more digging and came up with the solution. `OperationForm` must be modified using ModelChoiceFiled (as @efkin said) and `OperationCreate` should contains override for `get_form_kwargs` method from `ModelFormMixIn`:

```
class OperationCreate(CreateView, OperationMixIn):

    model = Operation
    form_class = OperationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_operations')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(OperationCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        operation = form.save(commit=False)
        operation.currency = Account.objects.get(pk=form.instance.account_id).currency
        self.update_account_balance(form)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(OperationCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```